# How to remove default Git or update it?

Tags: sudo, git

I cant delete or rename current version of git... Even with sudo...

```
MacBook-Pro-Kiril: $ sudo rm /usr/bin/git
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for /usr/bin/git?

MacBook-Pro-Kiril: $ sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple
mv: rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git-apple: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 11):

sudo `rm -rf /usr/bin/git` wont work for El Capitan due to SIP restriction

simple solution is create alias

```
alias git='/usr/local/bin/git'
```

Comment: What's a SIP restriction?

Comment: @Zorayr, it means "System Integrity Protection". You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection

Answer (score 2):

Use the below only if you want to remove the default GIT. You can still use package managers like homebrew and macports to install an alternative GIT.

---

The `/usr/bin` directory is restricted by SIP. You first need to temporarily disable it by booting to recovery, starting Terminal, and executing `csrutil disable` (then `csrutil enable` to re-enable`).

Once you have SIP disabled, you can remove git from `/usr/bin`.

See Also:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899 (About SIP)

---

Note: You can check for SIP restrictions with the `-Ol` flags with ls. If it isn't restricted, you will see a hyphen, and if it is, you will see restricted.

Comment: While this may be a way to remove it, the OP should use a package manager such as homebrew to install a newer version instead.

Comment: In defense of the OP, installing a newer version isn't effective unless you change your PATH (so that /usr/local/bin precedes /usr/bin) or create a `git` alias as suggested by @elliot-yap.

Answer (score 1):

I am generally not experienced enough to risk messing with system libraries (or anything that comes pre-installed with macOS). For this reason, I leave this answer for anyone else that may be in a similar situation.

My rule of thumb is that when something is in `/usr` that's a system resource and, generally speaking, I really shouldn't touch it (unless I really know what I'm doing, which I don't).

Answer (score 1):

### Please just install the Homebrew version of Git that is updated regularly.

#### Disabling SIP — and removing Git — can be done but it is honestly a bad idea.

While technically possible to do — as [John K’s answer states](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248229/40457) — by disabling SIP this is an incredibly short-sighted thing to do and might cause more headaches down the line. Especially when an OS update happens and the macOS version of `git` is reinstalled.

It is much better to just install an updated version of Git via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Just run this command, copied directly from the main Homebrew site, to install Homebrew if you don’t have it installed at all right now like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Once Homebrew is installed just run this command to install an updated version of Git like this:

```
brew install git
```

As of right now (February 9, 2023), it will install Git version 2.39.1. Confirm it is the version of Git that will be used when you type `git` by typing `which git`. On my Intel-based 2020 MacBook Air running macOS 13.2 (Ventura) system it shows the path as `/usr/local/bin/git`; which is the location of Homebrew installed version of Git and the parent directory contains other Homebrew installed binaries as well.

Comment: DOes your mac have an Intel processor - that path is not correct for Apple Silicon macs

Comment: On ARM, Homebrew installs to /opt/homebrew. On all platforms, `brew --prefix` will show the installation path.

Comment: Having said that: With recent versions of macOS, `/usr/bin/git` can't be replaced by the user anymore, so it's not just a bad idea...